# How to override version of pod dependency in flutter ios project

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods, podfile

I am using `flutter_facebook_auth` and `facebook_app_events` plugins.
One requires `FBSDKCoreKit` with version `13.0.0` and the other one with `13.1.0`.

When I want to run my app it fails because of this version conflict.
Is there a way to override the version all packages use in my project or do I have to update the version in the dependencies themselfes?

Comment: can you share a screenshot of the error